# How to stub Time.now.hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, time, rspec, stubbing

I have a helper method which outputs a greeting `#{greet(Time.now.hour)}` in the view pending the time of day:

users_helper.rb:

```
def greet(hour_of_clock)
 if hour_of_clock >= 1 && hour_of_clock <= 11
  "Morning"
 elsif hour_of_clock >= 12 && hour_of_clock <= 16
  "Afternoon"
 else
  "Evening"
 end
end
```

And I am trying to test this unsuccessfully as below:

users_feature_spec.rb

```
describe 'greeting a newly registered user' do
  before do 
    @fake_time = Time.parse("11:00")
    Time.stub(:now) { @fake_time }
  end
  it 'tailors the greeting to the time of day' do
    visit '/'
    fill_in 'Name here...', with: 'test name'
    fill_in 'Your email here...', with: 'test@test.com'
    click_button 'Notify me'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Morning'
  end
end
```

The test fails as the Time.now.hour is not being stubbed as intended above.

I've now tried all sorts of variations thanks to various advice, the two main reformats which it at least seemed were syntactically correct were:

```
describe 'greeting a newly registered user' do
  before do 
    @fake_time =  Time.parse("11:00")
    allow(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(@fake_time)  
  end
  it 'tailors the greeting to the time of day' do
      visit '/'
      fill_in 'Name here...', with: 'test name'
      fill_in 'Your email here...', with: 'test@test.com'
      click_button 'Notify me'

      expect(page).to have_content 'Morning'
    end
  end
```

and using the new ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers method #travel_to:

```
describe 'greeting a newly registered user' do
  it 'tailors the greeting to the time of day' do
    travel_to Time.new(2013, 11, 24, 01, 04, 44) do
      visit '/'
      fill_in 'Name here...', with: 'test name'
      fill_in 'Your email here...', with: 'test@test.com'
      click_button 'Notify me'

      expect(page).to have_content 'Morning'
    end
  end
```

But still I'm doing something wrong which means that `#greet` is still taking the live output of `Time.now.hour` and not using my stubbed or travel_to Time value. Any help please?

Comment: In RSpec 3 you can use `allow(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(@fake_time)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) (or the [new Rails replacement `travel_to`](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/rails-4-1-travel-to-test-helper/)) to stub out your time for you. With Timecop you can have super readable specs with no need for manual stubbing:

```
# spec setup

Timecop.freeze(Time.now.beginning_of_day + 11.hours) do
  visit root_path
  do_other_stuff!
end
```

Comment: Thanks Topher and definitely a good idea. Now I've gotten caught on this Time.stub thing i'd like to see it through to learn how to get it working manually. Maybe once I've got that nailed though i'll replace with the Timecop gem or the rails helper travel_to for learning purposes. Wow how much time these little code niggles take up!!

Comment: Word, I definitely agree that there's value in following through and learning stubbing. Good luck!

Comment: Topher, as per the above answer that i added, i gave up and took your Timecop suggestion, worked a treat first time. Any idea what was going wrong with my first approach though? Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it! I have no idea what was going on but I've seen some nasty subtle bugs arise from trying to stub too broadly, especially with complex and highly monkeypatched classes like Time. I've limited my stubbing to simple, well-known domain objects and will rarely stub on a class I didn't create.

Comment: I'm still stubbing of course, as this is the only way in which I can test a Time dependent method, rather now I'm just stubbing with another external dependency. Would have been nice to understand exactly what was up here. Hopefully someone else will be able to shed light on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
let!(:fake_hour) { '11' }
before do 
  allow(Time).to receive_message_chain(:now, :hour).and_return(fake_hour)
end
```

Comment: Thanks folks, have tried both formats and unfortunately neither seems to be stubbing the time out before the helper method #greet is called, strange !! I've tried changing the format of the argument in `Time.parse.format("11:00")`, no joy and double checked the helper method to confirm that it works ok which it does. Am at a loss here, any ideas?

Comment: Let's debug. Can your raise `hour_of_clock` inside `greet` method? `raise hour_of_clock.inspect` and let me know the output?

Comment: It raised 18, and we just crossed over into 19:00 so i tested again on the other side of the hour and perfect it gave me 19. Also outputs 'Evening' as intended when called in the view.

Comment: @user3346954, Updated my answer, can you try again?

Comment: Still failing to stub out Time.now. One deprecation warning on the `.stub` syntax specified in your answer, as hinted by @AbM, so changed to format suggested by @AbM; `allow(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(fake_time)`. Still failing though. Do you think it could be because I'm using `Time.now.hour` in the `#greeting` helper method thus i need to 'stub' that specific `Time.now.hour` method out put as opposed to just stubbing `Time.now`?

Comment: @jbk, I think you are right, you need to stub `hour` too.

Comment: Still failing `let!(:fake_time) { Time.parse('11:00') }
  before do 
    allow(Time.now).to receive(:hour).and_return(fake_time)  
  end`

Comment: Updated my answer, you can try that.

Comment: Object only allowed one argument as opposed to the proposed two `receive(:now, :hour)`. Changed to; `let!(:fake_hour) { '11' }
  before do 
    allow(Time.now).to receive(:hour).and_return(fake_hour)  
  end` and no longer has an ArgumentError but still not stubbing Time.now.hour

Comment: @jbk, can you try `receive_message_chain(:now, :hour)` ?

Comment: Sorry Sharvy, was hanging on here till v late last night waiting for your helpful responses, I just missed your answer in the comments as the relay is getting so long! Perhaps we should move this to chat, once we find the right solution we can report back here! Ok, so tried your `receive_message_chain` suggestion, throws the following error; `Failure/Error: visit '/'
       Double received unexpected message :to_default_s with (no args)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78822/discussion-between-jbk-and-sharvy-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to either stub out myself or use the `::TimeHelpers` method `#travel_to` :( and used the Timecop gem, worked first time as below:

```
before do 
    Timecop.freeze(Time.now.beginning_of_day + 11.hours)
end

it 'tailors the greeting to the time of day' do
    visit '/'
    fill_in 'Name here...', with: 'test name'
    fill_in 'Your email here...', with: 'test@test.com'
    click_button 'Notify me'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Morning'
end
```

I would really like to understand what was failing with my original approach though, does anyone see what was going wrong?